# Could not get the name of the current QuickBooks company data file

Tags: c#, quickbooks

Please help solve the following problem:

I'm in my WinForms application by QB SDK work with QB Desktop 2015.

1) I can successfully connect to and work with text files of the company.

2) If I try to connect to not test us, I get the following mistake - "Could not get the name of the current QuickBooks company data file."

Prompt please, in what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem. User QB company by which I worked was not the administrator.